# MongoDB - How to find null value in nested array of objects

Tags: mongodb

If I have documents that look like this:

```
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "key": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "key": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

... how can I find the document with 'key' set to null?

This is the query I've been trying, but I don't understand why it's returning both documents:

```
db.collection.find({
  "items.0.key": {
    $eq: null
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `null` not only matches itself but also matches “does not exist.” Thus, querying for a key with the value `null` will return all documents

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mongodb-the-definitive/9781449344795/ch04.html#sect2_d1e4021

**Workaround:** We need to perform a query with [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#available-types) operator.

```
db.collection.find({
  "items.0.key": {
    $type: 10
  }
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i09c3gvko15)

Comment: That works, but I should have explained that I'm looking for this document only if the items array contains only one object.

Comment: @CharlesJohnson updated my answer, please check again

Comment: I still don't understand.  Why would `$eq: null` return the second document when `items.0.key` clearly exists and is not null ?  And the rest of the quote is

> Thus, querying for a key with the value null will return all documents **lacking that key**

Comment: @aaaaaa This is due to a MongoDB issue https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27442. Essentially it is ambiguous what is meant by "items.0.key", since 0 can be the index of an item in an array or the key of any object in that array.

Comment: wow what a stupid design